# electrum windows client, standalone executable versus windows installer

Tags: client, installation, electrum

From the download page, http://electrum.org/download.html

1. What is the difference between the two windows versions? standalone executable and the windows installer version?
2. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each, and how should I choose which one I should use?

Answer (score 1):

1. The Windows Installer will install the executable in "Program Files", create shortcuts and other registry entries. The Standalone Executable is exactly that, just an executable to run the Electrum program.
2. Benefits of Windows Installer would be ease-of-use for those most familiar with installed programs, plus it will be available to multiple users (whether that is desired or not, is another question). Benefit of Standalone is don't create registry entires (cleaner) and don't require raised privileges (as not installing globally).

In either case - user-specific data will be saved in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Electrum`

There are some more details in this [blog post](http://superbitcoins.blogspot.ca/p/blog-page_19.html)

Comment: They also have portable now. It basically stores stuff in it's own folder instead of the local folders.

Answer (score -1):

Try this link - simple explanations and instructions:

http://www.bit-buddy.com/electrum-setup.html

Comment: while your link answers the question it is good to give a short overview of the link's contents in case the page expires and to save people time to assess whether it is useful to them.